# Piping 2 python scripts using python

Tags: python, pipe

I have 3 python files : 1 for accepting string, one for reversing it and one for piping them . I new to this concept , so please help me on how to achieve this.

1.py

```
def main():
    print 'Input Your String : '
    stri = raw_input()
    return stri

main()
```

2.py

```
import sys

if __name__=='__main__':
    for line in sys.stdin:
        sys.stdout.write(line[::-1])
```

pipe.py

```
import os

os.system('python 1.py | python 2.py')
```

All i want to achieve is feeding the output of 1.py to 2.py using another python file. Thanks !

Output:

```
$ python pipe.py
foo

 : gnirtS ruoY tupnI[tecomp@localhost 3264]$
```

Comment: any error or traceback?

Comment: executing pipe.py shows nothing . terminal hangs for some time .

Comment: did you give some values? `raw_input()` will get the input from user itself.

Comment: no values. just executed pipe.py and terminal hangs.

Comment: you need to give some values. Type, `foo` on that.

Comment: edited................

Comment: Well, it seems to work just fine to me. You can see it printing `gnirtS ruoY tupnI`. It does not print `oof` as `1.py` does not print print the result of `raw_input`.

Comment: what output do you actually want and why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no stdout except your print statement in 1.py, if you call main() with a `print main()` in 1.py then pipe the stdout of the process calling that script then your code would work, with `pipe.py` as the following piping the output of 1.py to 2.py:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, STDOUT

p = Popen(["python","1.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
p.wait()
p2 = Popen(["python", "2.py"], stdin=p.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
p.stdout.close()
out, _ = p2.communicate()
print(out)
```

1.py:

```
def main():
    return raw_input('Input Your String : ')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print main()
```

2.py:

```
import sys

if __name__=='__main__':
    for line in sys.stdin:
        sys.stdout.write(line[::-1])
```

Or using shell=True with check_output:

```
from subprocess import check_output

out = check_output("python 1.py | python 2.py",shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am partially able to make it work using the `subprocess` module. The python files are -

1.py - Here, instead of returning the input, you should print it.

```
def main():
    print 'Input Your String : '
    stri = input()
    print stri

main()
```

2.py -

```
import sys

if __name__=='__main__':
    for line in sys.stdin:
        sys.stdout.write(line[::-1])
```

pipe.py -

```
import subprocess
import sys
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python','1.py'] , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=sys.stdin)
output = p1.communicate()[0]

p2 = subprocess.Popen(['python','2.py'] , stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=sys.stdout)
p2.communicate(output)[0]
```

In the Pipe.py , we first call `python 1.py` while redirecting its stdin to the main script's stdin and redirecting the stdout to PIPE , so we can get the output in `output` variable.

Then we call , `python 2.py` while redirectings its output to main script's stdout and redirecting its stdin to PIPE , and then use `p2.communicate()` function to pass in the `output` variable as input to it.

The result is -

```
>> python pipe.py
Blah

 : gnirtS ruoY tupnI
halB
```

Please note, its partially working as we do not see the prompt from `1.py` . If that prompt is not necessary , we can also do -

1.py

```
def main():
    stri = input()
    print stri

main()
```

Then the result becomes -

```
>> python pipe.py
I inputted something

gnihtemos dettupni I
```